# What the meaning of this code `start = +start || 0;` in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am read the source code of node(v0.10.33), in the file `buffer.js`, i find this functiuon:

```
SlowBuffer.prototype.toString = function(encoding, start, end) {
  encoding = String(encoding || 'utf8').toLowerCase();
  start = +start || 0;
  if (typeof end !== 'number') end = this.length;

  // Fastpath empty strings
  if (+end == start) {
    return '';
  }

  switch (encoding) {
    case 'hex':
      return this.hexSlice(start, end);

    case 'utf8':
    case 'utf-8':
      return this.utf8Slice(start, end);

    case 'ascii':
      return this.asciiSlice(start, end);

    case 'binary':
      return this.binarySlice(start, end);

    case 'base64':
      return this.base64Slice(start, end);

    case 'ucs2':
    case 'ucs-2':
    case 'utf16le':
    case 'utf-16le':
      return this.ucs2Slice(start, end);

    default:
      throw new TypeError('Unknown encoding: ' + encoding);
  }
};
```

But i don't understand this line's meaning: `start = +start || 0;`, what's the purpose of `+` before `start`?

Here is the answer:
The + and - operators also have unary versions, where they operate only on one variable. When used in this fashion, + returns the number representation of the object, while - returns its negative counterpart.

```
var a = "1";
var b = a;  // b = "1": a string
var c = +a;  // c = 1: a number
var d = -a;  // d = -1: a number
```

> `+` is also used as the string concatenation operator: If any of its arguments is a string or is otherwise not a number, any non-string
>   arguments are converted to strings, and the 2 strings are
>   concatenated. For example, 5 + [1, 2, 3] evaluates to the string "51,
>   2, 3". More usefully, str1 + " " + str2 returns str1 concatenated with
>   str2, with a space between.

Comment: Just ensuring it's a number would be my guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns the numeric representation of the object.

See this [reference](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Operators)